# Reset Webform's SQL table indices?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm using webforms to get some data from users. These results are later used in another php script, and this relies on looping through the data:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($data); $i++)
    {
        $answers[] = $data[$i]["value"][0];        
    }
```

However, by adding and deleting questions in the webform, the indices look something like this now:

```
1
2
3
5
8
12
```

And this gives an error because I use `count()` to get the number of entries. (`count() = 6`, but `max() = 12`). My first idea is to find a way to automatically reset the indices after adding or removing questions. So my indices look like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

But I honestly have no idea how to go about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I got it, the question is not related to Webforms (which I'm not familiar with) but to PHP itself.

Besides "for each" option there is array_values() function. (If you don't want to change your script that processes the array).

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377630/how-to-re-key-array-with-non-sequential-numeric-keys) and [link](http://kr2.php.net/function.array-values)

Comment: This should do the trick, thank you! What I really wanted to do though, was reset the indices of the database itself. They are still not properly ordered there.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding you but I think you just want a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
  $answers[] = $item["value"][0];        
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
$answers = array_map(function($item) { return $item['value'][0]; }, $data);
```

Comment: Well, that I didn't think of that. I thought I *really* needed to use an index in my `$item` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `webform_get_submissions($nid);` loop the out put of this function using foreach. You will get the values without any issues.